# Unity | How to play animations that are stored in a variable (without having them in the animator)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm creating a 2D fighting game, where the player can choose from a number of fighters. the fighters have different attacks with different animations.

the data (damage, hitbox, cast time, animation, etc.) for every attack is stored in a Scriptable Object that is then triggered by the player script. this worked out fine so far, but I can't find out how to play an animation from code without needing it to be in the animator.

I've tried several solutions that I found here but they seem to end up having to fall back to putting the animation in the animator.

Comment: You can trigger animations in code - eg with a bool. For example, if you want the running animation to play while your user is pressing the 'A' key - is this what you want to do?

Comment: Give each alternative animation a trigger named like "attack1", "attack2" etc and set the animator with those triggers attached to the each animation. Then Set the triggers from your code randomly (if that is what you want). What is the reason for not wanting animation in animator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't find out how to play an animation from code without needing it to be in the animator.

You will need the [`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html)-Component to run an animation.

But you can assign the animation you want to play at runtime. For this you need the [`RuntimeAnimationController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html) to hold the `AnimatorController`-object and assign it to your `Animator` (in code).

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need the `Animator` component as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57885397/7111561).

There is also the [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) component. It is marked as [*legacy*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) but is still quite powerful especially when you do not need to configure an entire state machine but want to rather simply playback single `AnimationClip`. Might be the reason why this still makes it into newer Unity versions:

```c#
public AnimationClip clip;

private void Awake()
{
    var animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
    animation.clip = clip;
    animation.Play();
}
```

Also see [`Animation.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html)

Comment: Sounds risky to use a legacy component without cause just to skip creating a simple  AnimationController with *one* state. As Unity states: `This component is retained in Unity for backwards-compatibility only. For new projects, please use the Animator component.`

Comment: @aalmigthy Shortly after this question the *legacy* state was actually removed (see [`Animation` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html)) .. for good reasons like exactly this use case ;) Works a bit different now though API wise but concept stays the same

Comment: Thanks for evaluating, but I'm afraid you have something mixed up. The component is still in *legacy* state: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html. This is also described on this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html